# Clear out confusion: pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Just to clear out some confusion.
I encountered this code (using pointer to pointer) recently:

```
int encode(unsigned char type, uint64_t input_length, unsigned char** outputdata)
{
   unsigned char* p = *outputdata;

   *p++ = (unsigned char)type;

   for (int i = sizeof(uint32_t) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      *p++ = (unsigned char) ((input_length >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF);

   if(some condition) 
        *p++ = (unsigned char)(someInteger >> (input_length * 8) & 0xFF);  
   else
        *p++ = someStrValue++;  
   //..
}
```

So I think if you call this function like this:

```
unsigned char *output = malloc(128);
encode(2,32,&output);
```

Now, the data from `encode` method will be stored inside: `output[0]/*this will be type*/, output[1] /* 1st byte of input_length etc.*/, output[2],...` right?

My question is why was it necessary *in this case* to do it with pointer to pointer above?
Could not I do the same with single pointers? Like this:

```
int encode(unsigned char type, uint64_t input_length, unsigned char* outputdata)
{
       //unsigned char* p = *outputdata;

       *p++ = (unsigned char)type;

       for (int i = sizeof(uint32_t) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
          *p++ = (unsigned char) ((input_length >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF);

       //..
}
```

would have same effect as above right?

Called like this:

```
unsigned char *output=malloc(128);
encode(2,32,output);
```

Comment: You know you can try it and see what happens?

Comment: I suggest avoiding the phrase "double pointer"; it also refer to type `double*`. Just use "pointer to pointer".

Comment: @KeithThompson: ok done

Comment: Yes, you could have done that with a pointer. You don't need a pointer to pointer.

Comment: What's done? You still have the phrase "double pointer" in the first line of your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson: There were two occurrences of that word:)

Comment: Maybe it's justified, maybe it's not. One cannot tell based on a small fragment.

Comment: In your new code, you have an undeclared variable `inputdata` in use; is that a global variable (if so, yuck) or a typo for `input_length`?  The code is more confusing than it was before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's just a *normal* pointer to some data structure (I tried to shorten code for readability and only leave important/relevant parts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why was it necessary in this case to do it with double pointers above?

It wasn't. Whoever wrote that code is apparently not yet comfortable with the C language. Lets dissect the code a bit:

- `unsigned char** outputdata` There is absolutely no reason to use pointer-to-pointer.
- `(unsigned char)` Why use this when stdint.h is already included? Use `uint8_t`.
- `*p++ = (unsigned char)type;` The cast is superfluous. Why cast from unsigned char to unsigned char?
- `*p++` rather than trying to squeeze as many operators as possible into one single line, which gives absolutely no benefit, write readable code:

  ```
  *p = type;
  p++;
  ```
- `*p++ = (unsigned char) ((input_length >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF);` would benefit of getting split into several lines. Also, the masking is superfluous.

  ```
  *p = (uint8_t) (input_length >> (i * 8));
  p++;
  ```

Comment: Yes I also thought pointer to pointer was over used. about casting `type` it was enum, I quickly modified for readability... Thanks for feedback. (ps I will add other fragments for completeness)

Answer (score 0):

As so often, the answer may well lie in the code that isn't shown — specifically, there may be a reason for the pointer to pointer in the part of the code represented by:

```
//..
```

If that code contains:

```
*outputdata = p;
```

then it tells the calling function where the end of the converted data is.

If there is no code similar to `*outputdata = p;` in the function, there was no point in passing the pointer to pointer.  The only reasons I can think of for passing in a pointer to pointer are:

1. You need to modify/return the pointer (as in `*outputdata = p;`).
2. You need to conform to a specific function prototype or interface.

There's no easy way to spot that the latter is the reason, but if there was a family of functions with a similar interface, then one or more of the other functions might need to modify the output.  That's something of a stretch — the point of specific interface is to gain uniform behaviour, but if the behaviour isn't uniform, there's little benefit to it.

The code is formatting the data as a little-endian byte sequence; it will work the same on both little-endian and big-endian machines, though.

It is odd that the function takes a `uint64_t` and then only converts a `uint32_t`'s worth of the data.

Comment: There is no `*outputdata = p;` or similar in the code. Are you sure my example call is incorrect? The one you cited is for 'single' pointers ...(mostly method is like I showed in first snippet)

Comment: Ah, OK...too much similarity and misread...sorry.  I'll delete that section.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is where good function comments really help out.

Whether the function should take a pointer or a pointer-pointer depends on what it's supposed to do really.

```
unsigned char *output = malloc(128);
encode(2,32,&output);
```

So, the question is... does encode *ever* change the value of output?  Maybe it allocates its own buffer if you pass NULL to encode?  Maybe that's a feature that would make sense to add in the future?

Whether the buffer should be passed as a pointer or pointer-pointer depends really on the conceptual purpose of the method, not he implementation.  As a rule of thumb though, you want to dereference as little as possible; so all things being equal, prefer the single-pointer interface.